# ARIA live regions in OS X Voiceover

Tags: wai-aria, voiceover

I'm working on a web-based interactive-fiction text-adventure system, like this one.

http://eblong.com/zarf/glulx/quixe/quixe/play-remote.html?story=stories/Advent.ulx.js

The main section of the window, the "transcript," is a `<div>` with these ARIA settings.

```
<div
    aria-live="polite"
    aria-atomic="false"
    aria-relevant="additions"
>
```

It works pretty well in iOS Voiceover. A sample interaction goes like this:

> [two finger swipe up, Voiceover reads the whole page]
>   "... and down a gully."
>   [swipe right] Greater than. Text field. Double tap to edit.
>   [double tap, type E and press return] E. Inside Building. You are inside a building, a well house for a large spring. There are some keys on the ground here. There is tasty food here. There is a shiny brass lamp nearby. There is an empty bottle here. Greater than.
>   [double tap, type "get lamp", then return] Greater than. Get lamp. Taken. Greater than.

The "greater than" could probably have a nicer ARIA label ("command prompt"), but the point is that it's *conversational*. The user types something, Voiceover repeats it back to you, and then reads aloud the text adventure's response. Then you say something, then the game responds. That's the core loop of the game.

On OS X El Capitan 10.11.5 Safari 9.1.1, it doesn't work correctly. Initially it just focuses on the text field, not reading any of the text on the page, but at least I can page through it with VO arrows. Here's what I hear when I interact:

> [type E and press return] E. Inside Building. You are inside a building, a well house for a large spring. There are some keys on the ground here.

At that point, Voiceover stops talking, which is incorrect, because it should tell me about all of the other stuff in the room.

> [type "get lamp" and press return] Greater, edit text.

It's supposed to say "Taken." Continuing to interact with the game, Voiceover refuses to read any more words from the transcript unless I manually navigate to them with VO arrows.

I tried to make a reduced test case like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<body>
<div id=container aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="false" aria-relevant="additions">
<div>Here's some text.</div>
</div>
<form><input name=prompt></form></body>
<script>
container = document.getElementById("container");

// http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~robins/quotes.html
responses = [
    "Moral indignation is jealousy with a halo.",
    "Glory is fleeting, but obscurity is forever.",
    "The whole problem with the world is that fools and fanatics are always so certain of themselves, and wiser people so full of doubts.",
    "Victory goes to the player who makes the next-to-last mistake.",
    "Don't be so humble - you are not that great.",

]

document.forms[0].addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    appendDiv(event.target.prompt.value);
    event.target.prompt.value = "";
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * responses.length);
    appendDiv(responses[index]);
})

function appendDiv(text) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    container.appendChild(div);
}
</script>
</html>
```

If you type something in the input box, your message appears in the window, as well as a randomly selected quotation. When I try to read this in iOS Voiceover, it works great, reading back what you type and then reading the new quotation. On OS X Voiceover, it keeps reading and re-reading the entire page.

Are my ARIA attributes configured correctly? (Is this a bug on Apple's side?)